# Crosstab Totals row extra cell

Tags: crystal-reports, crosstab, crystal-reports-8.5

I need some help on crosstab in Crystal Reports 8.5, I have a spreadsheet that when exported to excel I get the following

```
        A   B   C   Total   
Jan     1   2   3   5   
Feb     4   5   6   15  
March   5   7   9   21  
Total       9   14  18  82
```

As you can see the total row has shifted one position to the right, 82 should be under total (which is the total sum of Jan+Feb+Mar)... how can I get this extra cell to be removed from my report?

Comment: Is the crosstab the only thing in the report? I'm not sure if it'll help, but try putting a vertical guideline to the left of the last column's fields (and make sure they're snapped to the guideline).

Comment: Actually there are headers which hold the column names, then you have the cross tab and the Total Column and Total Row are added by the cross tab itself. so the first data in the total row is shifted to the right making all the contents to go to the right as well.

Answer (score 0):

Although Crystal and Excel can both be used for reports, they have very different structures and philosophies.  So it's no surprise that exporting to Excel can be tricky.

Make sure your row header, field values, and total fields line up at *exactly* the same horizontal position.  Also check your Excel export options.

Comment: The problem is that the Total row cannot be modified since it's part of the cross tab and it shifting one pos to the right just like in the table I draw